# Contract jar attachment, though deleted at the beginning, re-appeared in Accepting Party node just after starting the flow from Initiating Party Node

Tags: corda

**Network configuration**
1 Notary,
3 Nodes - Party A, Party B, Party C

**Summary**
While following section "Potential .jar injection" at https://training.corda.net/prepare-and-discover/see-db/, I noticed that contract jar attachment, though deleted at the beginning, re-appeared in Party B node_attachment and node_attachment_contract table just after starting the flow from Party A(which had failed due to no reply from Party B due to contract jar missing in node_attachment and node_attachment_contract table). Why is this happening? Why contract jar re-appeared at Party B node?

**Details**
I first removed contract jar from Party B node(cross-checked at both node_attachments and node_attachments_contracts table and both were empty) and then started the flow from Party A via

> flow start ExampleFlow$Initiator iouValue: 50, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"

but just after running the flow, the contract jar attachment reappeared at both node_attachments and node_attachments_contracts table of Party B. Why is it happening? When I checked the entry at node_attachments table of Party B, I find following:

| ATT_ID | FILENAME | INSERTION_DATE | UPLOADER | VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E3C04EE4DBB0B65EFC5F299EFF1CC9CB7190021ECECB1505C2E7FD54F778C1A2 | null | 2021-03-11 20:20:03.409 | p2p:O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB | 1 |

while the same at Party A is like this:

| ATT_ID | FILENAME | INSERTION_DATE | UPLOADER | VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E3C04EE4DBB0B65EFC5F299EFF1CC9CB7190021ECECB1505C2E7FD54F778C1A2 | CorDapp Example | 2021-03-11 20:15:59.944 | app | 1 |

**Queries**

1. Why contract jar re-appeared at Party B node?
2. If we carefully look at column values, we see that yes the attachment insertion was made to Party B node just after running the flow from Party A(notice the insertion_date column) and the insertion was made by none other than the Party A itself(notice the uploader column; in normal case, attachment upload/insertion happens via app). But why Filename column is null?
3. Even though contract jar attachment was inserted in Party B node after running the flow from Party A, when I ran the same flow again from Party A, the flow threw the same error(Counter-flow errored) which it threw when attachment was not present in Party B node. Why is it throwing the error even after the attachment has got inserted in Party B node.  Then what is the point of it getting inserted?

Answer (score 1):

1. When you run a transaction from point A to point B, usually the attachment will be downloaded from A to B in order to verify the transaction. (especially if you use something like ReceiveTransactionFlow). That's why the attachment entry is on the other machine as well.
2. This is interesting, I've never tried to download an attachment from a different corda node before. If I had to guess the designers of the mechanism didn't feel it was necessary to store the filename as they have the has to uniquely identify it.
3. I don't want to be too speculative about what happened here, but it depends on the flow implementation. It might just be that the order of operations was different than you expected. For example you could use a subflow to send the attachment (or corda could be doing it automatically), and that attachment could finish being shared before the error that caused your flow to fail. In that scenario what I suspect is that the error in your flow is unrelated to the attachment process. This would make sense given the attachment code is very well tested.

One last note I would make is that the training.corda.net site is unfortunately  out of date (it was written for corda 4.5 I believe). So it might be worth double-checking that you've got the right version for the tutorials.

For some extra resources on this:

- Corda docs page on transaction attachments: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/tutorial-attachments.html

Comment: Thanks, I am running Corda 4.4 so training.corda.net should be fine I guess. Error in the flow("Counter-flow errored") came first time due to missing contract jar attachment which I had manually deleted in the beginning but in my understanding error should not have come second time because contract jar attachment is now present due to automatic re-insertion.